# Close descriptor for writing or reading at the end of script?

Tags: bash, pipe

Create a named pipe at the beginning of bash script.

```
fifo_file=fifo.pipe
mkfifo $fifo_file
exec 6<>$fifo_file
```

When job is done,should i close descriptor for writing or reading at the end of script?
code1

```
fifo_file=fifo.pipe
mkfifo $fifo_file
exec 6<>$fifo_file
some_code_omit
exec 6>&-
```

code2

```
fifo_file=fifo.pipe
mkfifo $fifo_file
exec 6<>$fifo_file
some_code_omit
exec 6<&-
```

Which should i choose `exec 6>&-` or `exec 6<&-`?Do they differ?

Comment: https://unix.stackexchange.com/questions/131801/closing-a-file-descriptor-vs

Comment: They don't differ.